# Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'radians'

Tags: php, mysql

trying to use a query to get the distance from a certain location utilizing this query.  we have the distances/locations set up in a db already.  here's the query:

```
$query = "SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM textloc HAVING distance < 20000 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1;";
```

it keeps returning 'Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'radians' within the console.  Obviously I'm doing something wrong here.  any advice?

Comment: Have you tried putting the php functions outside the mysql query string like ".$variable." or ".cos($variable)."?

Comment: Print out `$query` after variable substitution.  95% of the time, the answer is obvious.

Comment: `* cos( radians( lat )` Should that be `* cos( radians( $lat )`?

Comment: @peter tried that and still didn't work.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is a late reply, but for all of you that are facing this issue:

This error means that the function is missing the parameter, in other words, it means that you are sending something like this to mysql

```
select radians();
```

This is not caused by a NULL nor caused by an empty value or by a missing column. In this situations radians() will return a different result:

```
select radians(NULL); #->returns NULL
select radians(''); #->returns 0
select radians(wrong_collumn); #->returns: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'wrong_collumn' in 'field list'
```

I hope this help out :)